# How do I get the "Open in Safari" icon to appear when sharing a URL using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios8-share-extension

I'm struggling to get my application to share a URL properly so that the "Open in Safari" and "Open in Chrome" activity items show up in the share sheet.  I've tried sharing the URL a few different ways:

```
NSURL *data = _article.url;
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[data] applicationActivities:nil];
```

- As an NSData item using [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:];
- As an NSURL
- As an NSString using [myURL absoluteString];
- With combination of NSURL (the url) and NSString (the title)

For reference, these are the two activity items I'm trying to get to show up.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There a few (small) libraries you can use that provide custom `UIActivity` controls to get the "Open in Safari" and "Open in Chrome" activity items.

- Safari: [TUSafariActivity](https://github.com/davbeck/TUSafariActivity/)
- Chrome: [ARChromeActivity](https://github.com/alextrob/ARChromeActivity)

  ```
  @IBAction func shareClick(_ sender: Any) {
     var sharingItems = [AnyObject]()
     var sharingActivities = [UIActivity]()

     sharingItems.append(URL(string: shareURL)! as AnyObject)
     sharingActivities.append(TUSafariActivity())
     sharingActivities.append(ARChromeActivity())

     let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: sharingActivities)
     activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem =    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
     self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```

Even more custom `UIActivity` controls can be found on https://github.com/shu223/UIActivityCollection

Answer (score 3):

It appears there is a very popular library "SVWebViewController" for displaying in app web views.  The library also contains some nice activity items that you can use to do this.

https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController

Here is an example of the code you can use to make it work (don't forget to include the headers in your code as well)

```
#import "SVWebViewControllerActivityChrome.h"
#import "SVWebViewControllerActivitySafari.h"

- (void)share:(id)sender {
    NSArray *activities = @[[SVWebViewControllerActivitySafari new], [SVWebViewControllerActivityChrome new]];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[_article.url] applicationActivities:activities];
}
```

Comment: It really sucks on Apple's part to not have a built-in option for Safari when sharing NSURLs.